"Cucumber @ParameterType Named Parameter Not Recognized in IntelliJ"
I'm using @ParameterType in Cucumber to define a custom type and assigning a name to it. However, when I reference this name in my @Then step definition, the step in my feature file still shows as unmatched (undefined). Could this be due to an issue with IntelliJ IDEA, or is there potentially something wrong with my code setup?
Any insights into what might be causing this mismatch would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
feature file
step definition
